# Help identifying this Queen Ant

Tags: species-identification, ant

Could someone please help us identify this queen ant ?  We live in the North Island of New Zealand. So far our google image searches haven’t found a match. Any help would be appreciated. [image]

Comment: Any chance of more photos? if you can, to count the teeth in the jaws at the front, number of segments in antennae, segments on abdomen etc. from above also.